# C++ - Why does a static string give slightly different addresses when referred to by different functions?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, struct, memory-address

Just trying to get to grips with the intricacies of C++ and therefore am messing around with strings and pointers. However, I have come up against something I don't really understand.

First off, I am using the same function and I far as I know giving it the same argument each time. I am calling it from the main and from another function and getting slightly different addresses from each. The function that reads out data from certain parts of memory is below.

```
void printDataFromAddressForLength(char* pointer, long length)
{
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        cout << "&pointer: " << &pointer + i << "\tData: " << pointer + i << endl;
    }
}
```

The goal of this function is to print on each line, the current address and value, then iterate and be usable from anywhere doing the same thing - very simple function with no real purpose.

This is the code I have in my main()

```
MessageData messageData = returnStruct();
printDataFromAddressForLength(messageData.pChar, messageData.length);
```

I am also calling the printDataFromAddressForLength from my returnStruct() function. This code can be seen below.

```
// Returns MessageData from function 
MessageData returnStruct()
{
static string staticTestString = "Time and time again";

MessageData metaData;
MessageData* pMetaData = &metaData;

pMetaData->pChar = &staticTestString[0];
pMetaData->length = staticTestString.length();

printDataFromAddressForLength(pMetaData->pChar, pMetaData->length);

return metaData;
}
```

The output below comes from the printDataFromAddressForLength() function called from inside return struct. Note: 0x0027F**7**

```
&pointer: 0027F7BC      Data: Time and time again
&pointer: 0027F7C0      Data: ime and time again
&pointer: 0027F7C4      Data: me and time again
&pointer: 0027F7C8      Data: e and time again
&pointer: 0027F7CC      Data:  and time again
&pointer: 0027F7D0      Data: and time again
&pointer: 0027F7D4      Data: nd time again
&pointer: 0027F7D8      Data: d time again
&pointer: 0027F7DC      Data:  time again
&pointer: 0027F7E0      Data: time again
&pointer: 0027F7E4      Data: ime again
&pointer: 0027F7E8      Data: me again
&pointer: 0027F7EC      Data: e again
&pointer: 0027F7F0      Data:  again
&pointer: 0027F7F4      Data: again
&pointer: 0027F7F8      Data: gain
&pointer: 0027F7FC      Data: ain
&pointer: 0027F800      Data: in
&pointer: 0027F804      Data: n
```

This output comes from the printDataFromAddressForLength() function called from the main itself. Note: 0x0027F**8**

```
&pointer: 0027F8BC      Data: Time and time again
&pointer: 0027F8C0      Data: ime and time again
&pointer: 0027F8C4      Data: me and time again
&pointer: 0027F8C8      Data: e and time again
&pointer: 0027F8CC      Data:  and time again
&pointer: 0027F8D0      Data: and time again
&pointer: 0027F8D4      Data: nd time again
&pointer: 0027F8D8      Data: d time again
&pointer: 0027F8DC      Data:  time again
&pointer: 0027F8E0      Data: time again
&pointer: 0027F8E4      Data: ime again
&pointer: 0027F8E8      Data: me again
&pointer: 0027F8EC      Data: e again
&pointer: 0027F8F0      Data:  again
&pointer: 0027F8F4      Data: again
&pointer: 0027F8F8      Data: gain
&pointer: 0027F8FC      Data: ain
&pointer: 0027F900      Data: in
&pointer: 0027F904      Data: n
```

As far as I can tell I am first calling that function, passing in a pointer and length.

Then I am returning the struct that contains those two parameters to the main and calling the same function with what I expected to be the same parameters, length clearly is the same but pChar has a strange address increment.

Would be grateful for any insight!

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're printing the address of the formal parameter 'pointer', not the address of the string.

```
void printDataFromAddressForLength(char* pointer, long length)
{
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        cout << "&pointer: " << (void*)(pointer + i) << "\tData: " << pointer + i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, this did indeed work. Would you be able to explain though why casting (pointer + i) as (void*) makes it work?

Comment: @mgibson: `std::ostream::operator <<(char*)` assumes that the pointer is to a C string, and prints the string being pointed to.  If you want to print the actual pointer instead, you have to make it a pointer to `void`.

Comment: What @cHao said, plus the other change I made is that I removed the address-of operator from your code.

Answer (score 4):

Your'e not printing what you think you are. The type of `&pointer` is `char * *` : a pointer to a pointer. And you then add `i` to it, which increments it by the size of the pointed-to type (not `char`, but `char *`)

Try this:

```
cout << "&pointer: " << (void*)&pointer[i]
```

Comment: Changing the + i to [i] replaced the address with the same text as was on the right

Comment: Also if it is incremented by 0x100 the second time round and all I am talking about are chars, longs and pointers, is that not a pretty big increment and fairly orderly as well as everything else is the same. I get what you are saying about pointer to pointer and that is a good pointer. I just am not following the second part from seeing the 0x100 increment and trying to match it to anything

Comment: @mgibson : Sorry - it still needed the void* cast. I forgot that when `cout` `char*` as array of character, rather than just writing the address like it does for other pointer types.

Comment: @mgibson : re. 0x100 increment : You're basically printing the address of the pointer, (not the address of the string) and the pointer is stored on the stack. The compiler can pretty much do what it likes with that stack, but in particular, two `MessageData` objects are likely to be allocated on it. what is `sizeof()` one of those? (2, because the function returns one, and you have a local one within the function)

Comment: sizeof(messageData) = 8 bytes. So am I right in saying, because the "pointer" being passed into second call of that function in the main is a copy (was got using messageData.pChar (copy) instead of messageData->pChar (pointer to pChars address) a separate pointer was created still pointing to the same data but a copy nevertheless. Because this is a copy, printing the &pointer for each, gives a different addresses because they are both stored on the stack (which the compiler can use as it pleases) and there may well be data between them?

Comment: Fairly ambigious stuff at the moment, sorry if that makes no real sense at all! :P Just doing a project where I ideally need to be knowing these ins and outs and oh there are plenty!